# Cannot pass parameters to boost::thread constructor

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, c++17

I have two functions defined inside TEST_SUITE TEST_CASE. I am developing on Visual Studio 2019 v16.3.9 and have also run tests on Ubuntu.

```
auto bulk_messaging = [&](std::shared_ptr<pml_webserver::ws_handler> whoosh, std::string& bulk_text, std::string& keystr)
{
    // code omitted
}
auto tracked_messaging = [&](std::shared_ptr<pml_webserver::ws_handler> &whoosh, std::list<std::string>& keystrings)
{
    // code omitted
}
```

I can successfully call these from within a SUBCASE.

```
bulk_messaging(wsPrior, very_long_string, text_key);
tracked_messaging(wsCentral, central_keys);
bulk_messaging(wsFollower, lots_of_numbers, number_key);
```

I would like to run them simultaneously inside threads but have not been able to get anything to compile. The code

```
boost::thread t1(&bulk_messaging, wsPrior, boost::ref(very_long_string), boost::ref(text_key));
t1.join();
```

Causes an error that ends with

```
psoc_lib_plugin_test.cpp(1048): note: see reference to function template instantiation 'boost::thread::thread<_DOCTEST_ANON_SUITE_13::_DOCTEST_ANON_FUNC_14::<lambda_952ddee667f9559e5a67f99a19459356>*,std::shared_ptr<pml_webserver::ws_handler>,boost::reference_wrapper<std::string>,boost::reference_wrapper<std::string>>(F,A1,A2,A3)' being compiled
  with
  [
      F=_DOCTEST_ANON_SUITE_13::_DOCTEST_ANON_FUNC_14::<lambda_952ddee667f9559e5a67f99a19459356> *,
      A1=std::shared_ptr<pml_webserver::ws_handler>,
      A2=boost::reference_wrapper<std::string>,
      A3=boost::reference_wrapper<std::string>
  ]
```

And the code

```
boost::thread t2(&tracked_messaging, boost::ref(wsCentral), boost::ref(central_keys));
t2.join();
```

Causes an error that ends with

```
psoc_lib_plugin_test.cpp(1051): note: see reference to function template instantiation 'boost::thread::thread<_DOCTEST_ANON_SUITE_13::_DOCTEST_ANON_FUNC_14::<lambda_8f6672069634168b5ecabedf95db1e26>*,boost::reference_wrapper<std::shared_ptr<pml_webserver::ws_handler>>,boost::reference_wrapper<std::list<std::string,std::allocator<_Ty>>>>(F,A1,A2)' being compiled
      with
      [
          _Ty=std::string,
          F=_DOCTEST_ANON_SUITE_13::_DOCTEST_ANON_FUNC_14::<lambda_8f6672069634168b5ecabedf95db1e26> *,
          A1=boost::reference_wrapper<std::shared_ptr<pml_webserver::ws_handler>>,
          A2=boost::reference_wrapper<std::list<std::string,std::allocator<std::string>>>
      ]
```

I do not understand the documentation as the examples only pass **int** parameters. The template expansions also contain an **int** or a **long** parameter at the end (bind.cpp lines 319 and 398).

How can I pass these parameters to my threads?

Comment: `boost::thread t1(bulk_messaging, ...)` . Note no ampersand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By specifying `thread(&bulk_messaging,...)`, you are passing a pointer to the lambda as the first parameter.

Pointers to objects are not *Invocable*, even if the object itself is.

You either need to pass the lambda directly (`thread(bulk_messaging,...)`), which will *copy* the lambda object into the thread, or pass a reference to it (`thread(std::ref(bulk_messaging),...`) to avoid the copy. In the latter case, you will need to ensure that your lambda outlives the thread.

Comment: Thanks. I got link errors but they were solved by adding `find_package(Boost COMPONENTS thread REQUIRED)` and `target_link_libraries(Boost::thread)` to my **CMakeLists.txt** file.